# Sails.js:Pass csrf token in angularjs post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

Here is form  with csrf token

```
<form name="form" method="POST" ng-submit="login(user)" novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="user._csrf" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
......
....

</form>
```

How can i pass this csrf token with `http.post` request

```
$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
         $scope.login = function (user) {

             //user login as post
             $http.post('/login',user).then(function (response) {
                 console.log(response.data);
             });
         }
```

When i submit the above request i will get csrf token not found error

Here is sails.js documentation about csrf http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/csrf

Comment: Is your view rendered from sails controller?

Comment: It's an Ajax request

Comment: Use inspect element in browser, and confirm that you've value set for `_csrf`